# WP ACF Generate php – Where and how to put the code?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

On my WordPress website I have the ACF plugin installed and I'm using the fields on several pages in the 'regular' way. So I created the groups and fields in the backend. Everything works fine.

Now I want to generate php code of a couple of those field groups (because I want to change the code slightly). Where do I put the code and what’s the best way to do this?

I've created a new php file acf-deals.php and uploaded it to the /php-includes/ directory in the root directory. It includes the following code:

```
<?php

if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_deal1',
    'title' => 'Deal One (displayed on homepage)',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5c66e017f8359',
            'label' => 'Title',
            'name' => 'deal_title_one',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => '(max. 100 characters)',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => 'deals-title',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => 100,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5c6d43781bcb1',
            'label' => 'Deal or Discount',
            'name' => 'discount_deal_or_special_one',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => array(
                array(
                    array(
                        'field' => 'field_5c66e017f8359',
                        'operator' => '!=empty',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'choices' => array(
                'Discount' => 'Discount',
                'Deal' => 'Deal',
            ),
            'allow_null' => 1,
            'other_choice' => 0,
            'default_value' => '',
            'layout' => 'vertical',
            'return_format' => 'value',
            'save_other_choice' => 0,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5c66e094f835a',
            'label' => 'Description',
            'name' => 'deal_description_one',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'instructions' => '(max. 600 characters)',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => array(
                array(
                    array(
                        'field' => 'field_5c66e017f8359',
                        'operator' => '==empty',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => 'deals-description',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'maxlength' => 600,
            'rows' => '',
            'new_lines' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5c66e0d4f835b',
            'label' => 'Regular price',
            'name' => 'regular_price_one',
            'type' => 'number',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => 'deals-regular-price',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '$',
            'append' => '',
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
            'step' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5c66e130f835c',
            'label' => 'Discounted price / deal price',
            'name' => 'discounted_price_one',
            'type' => 'number',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => 'deals-discounted-price',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '$',
            'append' => '',
            'min' => '',
            'max' => '',
            'step' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5c703c1fd5851',
            'label' => 'Valid until',
            'name' => 'valid_until_one',
            'type' => 'date_picker',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'display_format' => 'm/d/Y',
            'return_format' => 'm/d/Y',
            'first_day' => 1,
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'post',
            ),
            array(
                'param' => 'post_format',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'aside',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_format',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'status',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 1,
    'position' => 'acf_after_title',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => 1,
    'description' => '',
));

endif;

?>
```

I've added this code to my single-aside.php file:

```
<?php get_template_part( '/php-includes/acf-deals.php', 'acf-deals' ); ?>
```

Unfortunately the field are not showing up in the WP admin backend. What am I doing wrong? I searched and searched but can't find a proper explanation or a way to fix it. I hope someone can help.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('acf/init', function(){ 
    ... add local fields
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer for fellow programmers; who might understand how it helps to solve the problem.